# Animate resize width of UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uibutton

I'm having some troubles animating the resize of the width of my button. This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)profileButtonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImage *buttonProfileDefault = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profile_Button_Default"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 3, 3, 3)];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:buttonProfileDefault forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIImage *buttonProfileDefaultDown = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"Profile_Button_Default_Down"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 3, 3, 3)];
    [sender setBackgroundImage:buttonProfileDefaultDown forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    [sender setTitle:@"LOG OUT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    sender.titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    sender.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

    // Animate
    CGRect originalFrame = sender.frame;
    originalFrame.size.width = sender.frame.size.width+60;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 animations:^{
        sender.frame = originalFrame;
    }];
}
```

It changes the width of the button (unless I take away the piece of code that changes the title), but it doesn't do it by animating it.

Any suggestion what might be wrong?

**Update**

So I've managed to animate the width change but putting the setTitle in the animate section, but it doesn't get the right width for the text itself (image below). How can I make this happen?

[image]

**Solution**

So I ended up placing the uibutton programatically. Seems like the autolayout was causing the problem.

Is it just me or is a lot of things kind of clumsy in Objective C?!

Comment: I copied your exact code and tried it in iOS 6 simulator. It works fine for me. Try setting duration as 1.5f and check if that makes any difference.

Comment: It doesn't. It changes to the new size, but it doesn't animate to the new size. Thanks for checking it out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure then. Could have checked if I was able to reproduce the same issue. How are you checking this and in which OS? Is there anything else related to this? And normal animations are working if you put it somewhere else?

Comment: I can animate the position, so it can come in from the side. But the width won't animate. I'm checking it in the iPhone simulator with iOS 6. If I take the "setTitle" away, it doesn't change the view at all.

Comment: Are you sure that sender is not nil when you are doing this? What if you declare your button as a class level variable and directly set frame here as `profileButton.frame = ...`

Comment: Doesn't work either. It seems if I put "setTitle down in the animation, then the change of width animates.

Comment: It seems weird you can't animate the width alone though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution

So I ended up placing the uibutton programatically. Seems like the autolayout was causing the problem.

Is it just me or is a lot of things kind of clumsy in Objective C?!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that your problem has to do with intrinsic content size. If that is set (which it is by default I think), then when you change the title, the button will change size, with no animation, without you doing anything in code. There's a couple of ways to fix this. The easiest, I think, is to expand the size of the button in IB by a little, even one pixel should be enough to get IB to set an explicit width (or you can just set that yourself). Then in code, you can do this:

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    [sender setTitle:@"Log Out Immediately" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button removeConstraint:self.lengthConstraint];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        self.button.frame = CGRectMake(self.button.frame.origin.x, self.button.frame.origin.y, 250, 44);
    }];
}
```

self.lengthConstraint is an IBOutlet to that length constraint set up in IB.

Another way to do it, is to change the constant in the constraint method using an NSTimer. This is one of the ways mentioned in the WWDC 2012 talk "Best Practices for Mastering Auto Layout":

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    [sender setTitle:@"Log Out Immediately" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.01 target:self selector:@selector(expandButton:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)expandButton:(NSTimer *) timer {
    self.lengthConstraint.constant += 2;
    if (self.lengthConstraint.constant > 170) [timer invalidate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `setTitle` before animating and do it in completion block.

```
    CGRect originalFrame = sender.frame;
    originalFrame.size.width = sender.frame.size.width+60;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.5 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews animations:^{
        sender.frame = originalFrame;
    } completion:^{
        [sender setTitle:@"LOG OUT" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }];
```

**Update:**
Check if you are using auto layout feature. I am not sure, but that should be the issue here. This works for me as I mentioned in comments when I create button programmatically.

Comment: Doesn't work. Still doesn't animate the UIButton width. Could it be something in the storyboard?

Comment: If you remove the setTitle part, is it animating?

Comment: Nope. Just tried to put a random new button in as well and it doesn't animate the width of that either. Weird huh?!

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk, Check if you are setting some constraints in story board? Are you using autolayout or so?

Comment: Ya, I'm using autolayout. It has a width constraint of greater than or equal to 35. Is that a problem?

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk, Can you please try removing that and check if it is working?

Comment: Well, I have to give it a width of some sort, otherwise the button doesn't show up.

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk, I am not sure about constraints, but is there an option to give a width which is flexible and there are no constraints which could cause this?

Comment: Ya, that's what I'm doing. I'm giving it a width of 35 or more.

Comment: I've updated the question. What do you think can be done there?

Comment: @HolgerEdwardWardlowSindbæk, Set your width to a bigger value to accomodate the button title. That should resolve it.

Comment: Also tried that. Didn't help. Ended up doing what I write in the above question. Think it's kind of clumsy though :-/.

Answer (score 0):

Once you start using auto layout you should stop modifying frames and instead modify the view's constraint values.

You could add an `IBOutlet` to the button's width constraint and modify its `constant` value.